# jQuery: Trigger different events at different scroll positions

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble triggering two events – one at one scroll position, one at another.
As you'll see below I'm trying to have `div` `#one` appear once the user reaches `300px`, while `div` `#two` will appear after `600px`.

CSS:

```
    <style type='text/css'>
        body {
            height:5000px;   
        }

        #base {
            position:fixed;
            width:300px;
            height:250px;
            margin-left:100px;
            margin-top:0;
            background-color:blue;   
            z-index:1;   
        }

        .feature {
            position:fixed;
            width:300px;
            height:250px;
            margin-left:100px;
            }

        #one {
            margin-top:250px;
            background-color:red;  
            z-index:2;    
            }

        #two {
            margin-top:500px;
            background-color:yellow;  
            z-index:3;    
            }

    </style>
```

JS:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(window).load(function(){
            $(document).ready(function(){

                $(document).scroll(function() {

                    var top = $(document).scrollTop();

                    if (top > 300) {
                        $('#one').show();
                    }
                    else if (top > 600) {
                        $('#two').show();
                    } 
                    else {
                        $('.feature').hide();
                    }   

                });
            });
        });

    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="base"></div>
    <div id="one" class="feature"></div>
    <div id="two" class="feature"></div>  
</body>
```

Comment: "I'm having trouble" - is not an explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem I see is with your if else logic.  If your top is greater than 300 it will do this:

```
$('#one').show();
```

but will then exit the conditional statement not checking the other if parts.

I have created a fiddle to show how the code could be done to acheive what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/fGWq5/

I also started the two divs with their display properties set to none so it wont display until triggered by the scroll event.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Thanks for the help – I definitely need to read up on proper logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
```

`window load` fires after `document ready` - so the way you have it nested, you'll get nothing happening.

Also, for future questions that you may ask, I suggest narrowing the problem down to a certain piece of code, rather than dumping the whole lot.

Comment: You're right. I'll be sure to do that moving forward. Thanks.